# Python how to solve Unicode Error in string

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm getting the classical error:

> ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 28: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

This time, I can't solve it. The error comes from this line:

```
mensaje_texto_inmobiliaria = "%s, con el email %s y el teléfono %s está se ha contactado con Inmobiliar" % (nombre, email, telefono)
```

Specifically, from the `teléfono` word. I have tried adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the beginning of the file, adding `unicode( <string> )` and also `<string>.encode("utf-8")`. Nothing worked. Any advice will help.

Comment: try adding `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to the top of the file as well, does that solve your issue?

Comment: What version of Python are you running? I have 2.7.12 and it works fine it just interprets that character as an escape sequence in the string literal

Comment: @ThomasTu Thanks man, ... That solves it. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in response to why this solves the issue OP is having, and somebackground on the issue OP is trying describe

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from builtins import str
```

In the default iPython 2.7 kernel :

(iPython session)

```
In [1]: type("é") # By default, quotes in py2 create py2 strings, which is the same thing as a sequence of bytes that given some encoding, can be decoded to a character in that encoding.
Out[1]: str

In [2]: type("é".decode("utf-8")) # We can get to the actual text data by decoding it if we know what encoding it was initially encoded in, utf-8 is a safe guess in almost every country but Myanmar.
Out[2]: unicode

In [3]: len("é") # Note that the py2 `str` representation has a length of 2.  There's one byte for the "e" and one byte for the accent.  
Out[3]: 2

In [4]: len("é".decode("utf-8")) # the py2 `unicode` representation has length 1, since an accented e is a single character
Out[4]: 1
```

Some other things of note in python 2.7:

- `"é"` is the same thing as `str("é")`
- `u"é"` is the same thing as `"é".decode('utf-8')` or `unicode("é", 'utf-8')`
- `u"é".encode('utf-8')` is the same thing as `str("é")`
- You typically call decode with a py2 `str`, and encode with py2 `unicode`.

  - Due to early design issues, you can call both on either even though that doesn't really make any sense.
  - In python3, `str`, which is the same as python2 `unicode`, can no longer be decoded since a string by definition is a decoded sequence of bytes.  By default, it uses the utf-8 encoding.
- Byte sequences that were encoded with in the ascii codec behave exactly the same as their decoded counterparts.

  - In python 2.7 with no future imports : `type("a".decode('ascii'))` gives a unicode object, but this behaves nearly identically with `str("a")`.  This is not the case in python3.

With that said, here's what the snippets above do :

- `__future__` is a module maintained by the core python team that backports python3 functionality to python2 to allow you to use python3 idioms within python2.
- `from __future__ import unicode_literals` has the following effect :

  - Without the future import `"é"` is the same thing as `str("é")`
  - With the future import `"é"` is functionally the same thing as `unicode("é")`
- `builtins` is a module that is approved by the core python team, and contains safe aliases for using python3 idioms in python2 with the python3 api.

  - Due to reasons beyond me, the package itself is named "future", so to install the `builtins` module you run : `pip install future`
- `from builtins import str` has the following effect  :

  - the `str` constructor now gives what you think it does, i.e. text data in the form of python2 unicode objects. So it's functionally the same thing as  `str = unicode`
  - Note : Python3 `str` is functionally the same as Python2 `unicode`
  - Note : To get bytes, you can use the "bytes" prefix, e.g. `b'é'`

The takeaway is this :

1. Decode on read/Decode early on and encode on write/encode at the end
2. Use `str` objects for bytes and `unicode` objects for text

Comment: `u"é".encode('utf-8')` is the same thing as `str("é")` is not true

Comment: That's good to know, do you think you can explain what's going on with `u"é".encode('utf-8') == str("é")` ?

Comment: The double equals calls the special method `__eq__` to check for equality. On those two objects it most likely is saying they are equal because they are both of `<type 'str'>`

Comment: @ThomasTu the meaning of `"é"` (a byte string) depends on the encoding of the file, eg. if the file is encoded in windows-1252, `"é" == "\xe9"` while if the file is encoded as UTF-8, then `"é" == "\xc3\xa9"`. `u"é".encode('utf-8')` unambiguously equals `"\xc3\xa9"`.

Comment: Thanks @roeland, that clarifies a lot! Will try to clarify my post to reflect this.

Comment: similarly, and **very important**, `u"é".encode('utf-8')` is not the same as `str("é")`.